# oVirt exported VM

Tags: virtualbox, ovirt

I made a backup of an oVirt managed VM and I'd like to check its integrity in other virtualization softwares.

Unfortunately, the import process fails in VirtualBox with the following error:

> Error reading "dec755be-d053-46a0-b93d-75364c0c5965.ovf": missing or invalid attribute 'capacity' in 'DiskSection'

With VMWare Player, I'm also dealing with an error:

> The import failed because dec755be-d053-46a0-b93d-75364c0c5965.ovf did not pass OVF specification conformance or virtual hardware compliance checks.

I didn't specify any option or made any config changes prior to the export, so I don't get why I'm facing this situation. Besides, I did a bit of research before asking for help but I didn't find any problem coming close to what I'm experiencing.

Any idea on that matter?

Answer (score 0):

The OVF format isn't standardised and is very very loose in terms of what goes in there. Every vendor does whatever they prefer in terms of the actual syntax for describing a VM, especially since not every vendor uses the same storage layout schemes and since virtual hardware differs between various hypervisors. In short, an OVF from any vendor will easily install only on products by the same vendor.

If you want to import the exported VM into another hypervisor, you better use a v2v solution for that hypervisor, or manually create a VM with the correct hardware and attach the exported virtual disks. You might have trouble with virtual hardware mismatch if you do this.